# -discord.py- Sorting JSON files without overwriting the entire file

Tags: python, json, sorting, discord.py

I have a JSON file in which I want the objects to be sorted.

This is a sample of how the JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "sample": [
    {
      "id": "csb210921-1",
      "date": "September 21, 2021",
      "time": "13:22",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "csb210924-1",
      "date": "September 24, 2021",
      "time": "00:26",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, whenever I append a new set of data and sort it (basically those under `sample`), the `sample` part gets removed. So it'll end up looking like:

```
[
    {
      "id": "csb210921-1",
      "date": "September 21, 2021",
      "time": "13:22",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "csb210924-1",
      "date": "September 24, 2021",
      "time": "00:26",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "csb210924-2",
      "date": "September 24, 2021",
      "time": "00:26",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    }
 ]
```

The code on discord.py right now looks like this:

```
@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
 # ... stuff here to put input
  with open('sample.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

    data['sample'].append({
      "id": img_id,
      "date": img_date,
      "time": img_time,
      "url": img_url
    })

    final = sorted(data['sample'], key=lambda x: x['id'])
  
  with open('sample.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(final, fp, indent = 2)
```

I would want to find a way to still sort the data without removing the parent key. How should I go about this?

Comment: Print `final`, you'll see why.

Comment: Yes, I know that the sort only looks at those under `sample` and that's what's ended up getting dumped. But my question is that I'm feeling a bit stumped on how I should sort it without affecting `sample`.

Comment: Just assign it to the key: `data["sample"] = sorted(dasta["sample"], key: lambda x: x["id"])` And save `data` -- `json.dump(data, fp, indent=2)`

Comment: Ah it worked, thanks !